# Eulers method solving 1. order differential equation in Matlab

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]I am trying to solve $\frac{du}{dt} =3ut^2$ with initial condition $u(0) =1$. The solution is $u(t)=\exp(t^3)$.

I have the following Matlab script:

```
u0=1; %initial condition
t0=-2; % initial time
tend=1.2; % final time
dt=0.05; %timestep
t=t0:dt:tend; % time grid
N=length(t);
u=zeros(1,N); % a vector with N zeros, to become the numerical solution
u(1)=u0; % put initial condition at first position in u vector
% Eulers method:
for n=1:N-1
    u(n+1)=u(n)+3*u(n)*t(n).^2*dt;
end
plot(t,u)
ylim([0 6])
xlim([-2 1.5])
```

It will give me a solution, but not the same graph as in the given solution.

I have tried to play with restricting $x$ and $y$ axes to make it look alike, but there's something wrong here. I suspect there an error in the for loop. I am grateful if someone could help me

One more thing:I don't quite understand this:
u=zeros(1,N); % a vector with N zeros, to become the numerical solution

As you may understand, this was given by my teacher to modify and I missed the lecture when he went trough this. (silly me)

I understand the Eulers method, but the Matlab part is new  to me.

Attached image showing the solution my teacher wants

Comment: Yes Matlab is maybe not a first choice for Euler method as it is iterative and for loops are not very fast in Matlab. u = zeros(...); is just to allocate the memory in Matlab, if Matlab would need to resize u for each new value we calculate then it would be even slower.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between the initial time and the value at the initial time. If you are using $u_0=1$ then $t_0=0$. In particular, modify the line

```
t0=-2;
```

to

```
t0=0;
```

To plot both curves on the same figure, replace

```
plot(t,u)
```

with

```
plot(t,u,t,exp(t.^3));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So my for loop was correct, thats good. I have edited my post to show the wanted solution from my teacher. If I set t0 =0 I get the correct graph from 0 and up. but I am asked to take time from -2 to 2.1. any suggestion?

Comment: You need to integrate backward with negative time step, `x[n-1]=x[n]+f(t[n],[n])*(-dt)`.

Comment: @BjørnOveSætre Use the method of LutzL if you want to ensure that $u(0)=1$. But the figure seems to be generated by $u(-2)=e^{-8}$. So setting `u0=exp(-8)` and `t0=-2` should generate the required curves.

Comment: exp(-8) gave me the correct figure and solution, But why?    integrate backward with negative time step mean that I should change my for loop to the one from lutz? I have tried playing with that but get error. Anyone have a suggestion as to the correct code with my variables?